# Spring AWS S3: How to upload an image and get a URL which shows it rather than downloads it?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-cloud

So my problem's that when I open the URL of the uploaded file, it downloads it. 
I did some research and the problem's that I should somehow specify to S3 that its an image.
Currently this's the function that handles the upload but I don't know how could I set the type there.
Or is there a built in function that recognises the images and when the URL is opened it shows them automatically rather than downloads them?

Thanks

```
public void writeResource(byte[] bytes, String fileName) throws IOException
{    
   Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("s3://bucket/" + fileName);
   WritableResource writableResource = (WritableResource) resource;
   try (OutputStream outputStream = writableResource.getOutputStream())
   {
      outputStream.write(bytes);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 @Autowired
 private AmazonS3 amazonS3;    

 ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
                       meta.setContentType(file.getContentType());
                       meta.setContentLength(file.getSize());
                       meta.setHeader("filename", fileName);

 ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());

 TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(this.amazonS3);
                 transferManager.upload(bucket, filename, bis, meta);
```

That's how I solved it. Hope this help someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are sending this data back to a browser(?). If you are sending the contents of the file back to a browser, you need to set the content-type of the response to indicate to the browser that the file is an image; to do this, you'll want to set the content-type to **"image/jpeg"**.

By specifying the content-type, the browser then knows what to do with the file (in this case, to render the image in the browser).

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I need to do, but don't know how. How can I set that programmatically?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question based on your code snipped in your question. From what/where does that code run? In a typical servlet based web-app you would write to the Response object and not to an OutputStream like you are doing. When writing to the Response object, you can set the content type. For example: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)